# wpf path data differences

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm trying to create a vector path made of multiple shapes. The desired goal is this...

[image]

However I've seen data for paths written in multiple ways. One way is like this..

```
M10,0L20,10 0,10z
```

This same path could be written like this...

```
M10.2042655289777,2.10534975661348L20.2042655289777,12.1053497566135 0.204265528977683,12.1053497566135z
```

Both snippets above create this shape.

[image]

From my own analysis I've discovered that the first snippet of code is scaleable and fits the contents of the button its placed in. Where as the second approach appears to be more exact coordinates of the path points. Is there any way i can create a path with exact coordinates and then convert it to the more general one like so **M10,0L20,10 0,10z**. Or if anything i can i create my desired shape while maintaining its scalability.

Here is my path data...

```
<Path Fill="Blue" Data="M16.5,4.50000035762787L25.5,4.50000035762787 25.5,17.5000002384186 16.5,17.5000002384186z M2.5,4.49999994039536L11.5,4.49999994039536 11.5,25.5000002384186 2.5,25.5000002384186z M0.5,0.5L27.5,0.5 27.5,1.50000023841858 0.5,1.50000023841858z"></Path>
```

I guess i could always use `Stretch="Uniform"`

Comment: Everything is scalable if it's inside `ViewBox`. If you create figures from head, then you will use first (`int`) coordinates, while vector editors operating with second (`float`).

Comment: How can i use a viewbox with my path data? I posted the code above

Comment: No Viewbox necessary. Just set the Width and Height of the Path element, and Stretch to Uniform.

Comment: @Clemens, `ViewBox` is necessary when you are copy/pasting `Path` created by some vector editor (I assume those are, because humans won't use coordinates with 10+ digits after decimal points). `Path` properties are then *hard-coded* (I mean you don't want to change `Path`'s size because then you have to go through changing all coordinates in `Data`, which is a lot of work), simply putting `Path` inside `ViewBox`, which size you adjust is the way.

Comment: @Sinatr Path can stretch, that's why it has a Stretch property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the shape all in one colour then you can use a single **path** object to define it.

```
<Grid Width="250" Height="250">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Path Margin="4" 
              Fill="Red" 
              Stretch="Uniform" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Data="M 0,0 L 100,0 L 100,15 L 0,15 z 
                    M 5,20 L 40,20 L 40,100 L 5,100 z 
                    M 60,20 L 95,20 L 95,70 L 60,70 z" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Note that because **stretch** is set to **uniform**, the display size of the path is constrained by the parent container. The coordinates used in the path element are just relative values. Changing the size of the grid will shrink the path drawing, keeping a 4 pixel margin from the border.

If you want to draw the shape in multiple colours then it becomes slightly more complicated. You can use multiple path objects, but in order to position them correctly, they all have to be coerced into the same coordinate system by using a pair of move values to define the overall size (still in relative units) at the start of each data string.

```
<Grid Width="250" Height="250">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Path Margin="4" Fill="Red" Stretch="Uniform" 
                  Data="M 100,100 M 0,0 L 100,0 L 100,15 L 0,15 z" />

            <Path Margin="4" Fill="Blue" Stretch="Uniform" 
                  Data="M 0,0 M 100,100 M 5,20 L 40,20 L 40,100 L 5,100 z" />

            <Path Margin="4" Fill="Green" Stretch="Uniform" 
                  Data="M 0,0 M 100,100 M 60,20 L 95,20 L 95,70 L 60,70 z" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>  
</Grid>
```

The second grid is required as a border can only have a single child.